# When/why can file.downloadUrl be empty for a PDF file selected from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

Using js file picker to select PDF files from Google Drive.
I'm encountering an instance when the `downloadUrl` is undefined.

I don't understand what can cause this.
I know `downloadUrl` can be empty for native Google formats, but these are PDF files.

I'd like to know what scenarios (except native Google formats) can cause an empty `downloadUrl`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response I was receiving was 403.
And the scenario was user accessing "work" Drive (Google Drive for your domain)

Turns out Google Drive for your domain Administrators can restrict the permission to install third party apps.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6105699?hl=en

User will still be able to allow access for the app and select files. Its just going to fail every time with a 403. Very confusing UX.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Drive API to fetch the picked files' metadata in order to retrieve the downloadUrl. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Native Google formats can be downloaded (converted and downloaded) via their exportLinks: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#exportLinks

Comment: It works fine for regular users. The picked files carry downloadUrl or exportLinks properties. There's no need for another call to fetch the metadata.
It fails in one particular case, when the user is accessing a "work" Drive (apps for your domain).